# Angular 4 project showing error on running

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I have cloned an angular 4 project from *GitHub*

[Git link here](https://github.com/s2pedutech/imsui1)

I have cloned this project then I have to install `angular CLI`
after that, I have run `npm install`. When I run the project by `ng serve`
it's giving me many errors like:

> Cannot find module '@nebular/theme' and  Cannot find module '@angular/core'

any help?

Comment: in your tsconfig.app.json inside exclude add this "node_modules", and try again

Comment: @AnishKapuskar did you run `npm install`? This is needed to install the npm-dependencies, which should generally not be commited to the repository.